# Custom functions: How to refer to another column using sym() and !! (bang bang) without using funs() in dplyr 0.8.0?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, nse

In `dplyr 0.8.0`, the wrapper `funs()` (used within `mutate_at()` or `summarise_at()`) is soft-deprecated.

The new recommended syntax is to use `~sum(.)` instead of `funs(sum(.))`, which is the "old style" I would have previously used. My aim is to translate the old syntax to the new syntax , however I have been experiencing issues when the function call within `funs()` uses (`!!sym()`) to convert a character input **for a column name** to a symbol that can be recognised within the function.

Here's a made-up example of how I would write a function in the old `dplyr` style.

`var` is a character string that refers to the column name, and at `funs()` it is multiplied by `Sepal.Length`.

```
multiply_by <- function(var){
  iris %>%
    mutate_at("Sepal.Length",funs(.*!!sym(var)))
}
multiply_by("Sepal.Width") # This works
```

My question is that I cannot figure out how to translate this to the new `~` syntax without encountering an error. If I run the following it triggers an 'invalid argument type' error:

```
multiply_by2 <- function(var){
  iris %>%
    mutate_at("Sepal.Length",~.*!!sym(var))
}
multiply_by2("Sepal.Width")
# Error in !sym(var) : invalid argument type
```

Can someone help? At the moment I can get by with using `funs()`, but since it is being soft-deprecated I would like to migrate my code to a stable format if/when it becomes fully hard-deprecated. Thank you!

Comment: Tryb `mutate_at("Sepal.Length", list(~.*!!sym(var)))`

Comment: Thanks - but this seems to trigger the same error - " Error in !sym(var) : invalid argument type "

Comment: Try `iris %>% mutate_at("Sepal.Length", list( ~ .* .data[[var]]))` as mentioned in the [issues](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4199)

Comment: Thanks - works like a charm! It's less of a 'dplyr' solution but solves my problem.

Comment: In the issue, there is also the `eval_bare` (`iris %>% mutate_at(vars(Sepal.Length), list( ~ eval_bare(expr(.* !! sym(var)))))`) but it would be better to use a simple solution

Comment: Agreed. It defeats the point of readability and using pipes when you need to use 3-4 extra functions to wrap a function call!

Comment: @akrun Why do we need to use !!sym() and not just !!(), sym() or get()?

Comment: @skan it is an old solution.  Some of the code blocks may not relevant i.e. `_at`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option as mentioned in the [issues](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4199) would be to use `.data`

```
multiply_by2 <- function(var){
 iris %>% 
       mutate_at("Sepal.Length", list( ~ .* .data[[var]]))

}

multiply_by2("Sepal.Width")
```